# Updating a list using React props and Axios doesnt function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-props

I have a list of objects received from an API in a list:

```
  refreshList() {
    axios.get('/api/jobs/list-locations/',{headers:headers}).then(res=>{
      this.setState({
        locations:res.data.map(Locations=>({label:[Locations.country,' ', Locations.region,' ',Locations.zipcode],value:Locations.id}))
      })
    })
    axios.get('/api/jobs/list-departments',{headers:headers}).then(resp=>{
      this.setState({
        departments:resp.data.map(departments=>({label:[departments.name,' ',departments.company_name],value:departments.id}))
      })
    })

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshList()
  }
```

and next to each of the lists I have a button which opens a form and the user can create a new location or a new department using those forms. I successfully post the locations and departments to the API, but I want my list to be refreshed when those new objects are added. so far this is what I have done:(continuing from the previous code:)

```
render() {
    let addModalLocationAdded = () => this.refreshList();
    let addModalDepartmentAdded = () =>this.refreshList();
    return (
         ...
 <Row>
          <Col xs={10}>
            <Select placeholder='Select from pre-created Locations'onChange={handleDropDown('Location')} defaultValue={values.Location} required options={this.state.locations}/> 
          </Col>
          <Col>
          <Button style={{position:'relative',left:'150px' }} onClick={()=>this.setState({addModalLocShow: true})} color='success'>
            New Locations
         </Button>
         <AddLocModal show={this.state.addModalLocShow} onHide={addModalLocClose} onLocationAdded={addModalLocationAdded}/>
          </Col>
        </Row>    
        <br />
        <Row>
         <Col xs={10}>
          <Select placeholder='Select from pre-created Departments'onChange={handleDropDown('Department')} defaultValue={values.Department} required options={this.state.departments}/>
         </Col>
        <Col>
          <Button style={{position:'relative',left:'150px', width:'130px'}} onClick={()=>this.setState({addModalDepShow: true})} color='success'>
            New Department
          </Button>
          <AddDepModal show={this.state.addModalDepShow} onHide={addModalDepClose} onDepartmentAdded={addModalDepartmentAdded} />
        </Col>
        </Row>
```

and then in my *(AddLocModal.js)* for example I used the `onLocationAdded` props like this so I refresh my list as soon as the new item is posted to the API:

```
handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('handlesubmitshot')
    const headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Token 3a4efb52af35873353a27491ffe54e6551c61391'
    }

    const location = {
      country: event.target.LocationCountry.value,
      region: event.target.LocationRegion.value,
      zip_code: event.target.LocationZipCode.value
    }
    axios(
      {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/jobs/set-location/',
        headers: headers,
        data: location
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
      })
      .then(
        this.props.onLocationAdded()
      )
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Modal
        {...this.props}
....
 <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
....
```

the thing is, that I receive an error, saying `this.props.onLocationAdded()` is not defined. I dont know where to put it so my list is updated as soon as info is posted. I used `componentDidUpdate` in my original file before but it only works when I only have a post method for a single form, and when I add the post method for department it throws me into an infinite loop and doesn't load, thats why I seperated my `refreshlist()` calls. how can I pass that props correctly so it gets updated?

Edit: I used it in my first `then()` too but it doesnt work there either

Comment: Use it in the first then(), where you receive the response.

Comment: @MohitArora it doesnt work

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this???

Comment: @MohitArora no my server is local so it wont work